# how to move multiple items into a listbox in infopath 2010

Tags: development, infopath, custom-form, form

I have an infopath form that has two list boxes. I'm wanting to be able to add multiple items from one listbox to another. similar to this :

[image]

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think I figured out another solution... created two multiselect boxes, then on the second one make that datasource be connected to the first. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with some programming into the InfoPath form. There is a blog post which describes this exact situation in detail -

http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/programmatically-move-items-between-two-lists-infopath.htm

Good Luck .